# How to apply math function to node value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have xml file with set of dates that are negative when it's BCE and positive if CE. I need to change the negative values to positive by multiplying by -1, how do i do that?

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="node &lt; 0">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="node"/> BCE</p> <!-- How to multiply by -1? -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="node"/> CE</p>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: What's the difference between `value` and `node` in your example?

Comment: node is the node name and value is its value like: `<parent><node>value</node><parent>`

Comment: Your test should look like this: `<xsl:when test="node &lt; 0">`.

Comment: yep you are right, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to change the negative values to positive by multiplying by -1,
>   how do i do that?

```
<xsl:value-of select="-node"/>
```

**Note**:

```
<xsl:when test="value < 0">
```

is not a valid expression; you must escape the < operator:

```
<xsl:when test="value &lt; 0">
```

Comment: thanks it worked like magic, does this mean that i can use any basic math function(+ - * /) inside the `select` parameter?

Comment: @razzak You can use the `+`, `-`, `*` and `div` operators, as well as `mod` and [number functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions).